# Is it possible to download only the Single Player part of PS4 games?

Tags: ps4, psn

I am going to move places, and my future home will have a hardly metered, low debit connection.

As such, I d like to download as much of my PSN library before moving out.
But a thing that take a LOT of place while being useless to me is the multiplayer part of the games. If I were to be able to select the part to download, I could double the stored library.

A option I found, but is higly impratical, is to download the game proper, which usually contain the single player part. After installation, the PS4 will try to download "Application Data", which is usually the multiplayer.
If you somehow make that download crash, you can still play the game in single player.

Problem is that that solution implies to be attentive to the download from almost start to finish, and require a way to crash the download too.

Is there a official/supported way to do that?

Comment: Nope, not really.

Comment: While I understand there was little chance of a official and supported answer, is it enought to warrant down votes?

Comment: @DrakaSAN Users can downvote for any reason.  Since games don't generally come in single player and multplayer components, this seems rather unreasonable, to me, anyways.

Comment: @Frank: Seeing the large and larger space taken by games, and the ridiculous size of the default hard drive, I don t see that as so unreasonable. Ever more when multiplayer easily take 2x the place of the single player part.

Comment: With hard drive space getting cheaper and cheaper, and the ease of swapping the hard drive, that seems to be a better option than trying to force a partial download.

Comment: I don't think your assertion that multiplayer taking up significantly more space is accurate. Oftentimes games will reuse assets heavily between modes. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @Frank: Granted.

Comment: @twobugs: BF4, download of the game proper took ~30G, and application data was wanting to get another ~30G, I may make assumption about other games, but I remember similar number for BFH and The Last of Us.

Comment: @twobugs That is very true for games with multiplayer that is relatively seamless with the single player game, Dying Light and GTA:V come to mind. But if it's something like CoD with separate maps or areas that are not available in single player, then the multiplayer mode would take up much more space.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the singleplayer and multiplayer component are different games(i.e. Black Ops 3 on PC has this) all together this is not doable.